# Issues with saving product on multiple stores in magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, product

I am having an issue while saving a product in Magento.

I have a product and have multiple stores (multiple groups and views).

- Example Website

  - Store Group 1

    - English
    - French
    - German
  - Store Group 2

    - Bangla
    - Hindi

Say I am editing the product for store `French` and clicked on save. But the thing is, the newly saved/entered value for store `French` is copied to all stores (`English`, `German`, etc.).

I need to save the values (even for price values) only for specified stores. Not to all of the stores.

If the solution is a programmatic way, I agree to go with that.

Thanks

**Newly Added:**

I also want to know  about saving `price, cost, special price, grouped price, tier price`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved the `price, cost, special price, grouped price, tier price` saving issues myself.

I searched on Google and got an extension called [Store View Pricing](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/store-view-pricing-3541.html) for free. That solved my 80% of the problem. It just gives the opportunity to save prices on a per store basis.

But, to make the other fields (cost, special price, grouped price, tier price) also behave like the price field/attribute, I needed to change the Scope (is_global: column name at DB) to `Store View` (0: set to DB). I did run the following query on DB:

```
SELECT ea.attribute_id, ea.entity_type_id, ea.attribute_code, ea.frontend_label, cea.is_global 
FROM `eav_attribute` AS ea 
INNER JOIN `catalog_eav_attribute` AS cea ON ea.attribute_id = cea.attribute_id
WHERE `attribute_code` LIKE  '%price%'
ORDER BY ea.`attribute_id` ASC
```

I found the attributes what I needed. And changed the `is_global` value of them to `0`.

After doing so, all is working fine as I need. I know this kinda manual process. I am trying to get a programmatic solution.

Answer (score 1):

before saving  set the storeId of the store you want to save the product for, same is working with loading a product

`$product->setStoreId('2')->setName('Name for Store 2')->save();`

`$product->setStoreId('2')->load(17)->getName()`

good luck!

Comment: Thanks @mischa-leiss for your answer. What about saving `price, cost, special price, grouped price, tier price`?

Comment: you cant save different prices for different store views. this is just working with different websites...

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue in 1.5

i overide app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Model\Resource\Eav\Mysql4\Abstract.php

```
protected function _insertAttribute($object, $attribute, $value) {
        /**
         * save required attributes in global scope every time if store id different from default
         */
        $storeId = Mage::app()->getStore($object->getStoreId())->getId();
        if ($attribute->getIsRequired() && $this->getDefaultStoreId() != $storeId) {

                $bind = array(
                    'entity_type_id' => $attribute->getEntityTypeId(),
                    'attribute_id' => $attribute->getAttributeId(),
                    'store_id' => $this->getDefaultStoreId(),
                    'entity_id' => $object->getEntityId(),
                    'value' => $this->_prepareValueForSave($value, $attribute)
                );
                $this->_getWriteAdapter()->insertOnDuplicate($attribute->getBackend()->getTable(), $bind, array('value'));
            }
```

to

```
protected function _insertAttribute($object, $attribute, $value) {
        /**
         * save required attributes in global scope every time if store id different from default
         */
        $storeId = Mage::app()->getStore($object->getStoreId())->getId();
        if ($attribute->getIsRequired() && $this->getDefaultStoreId() != $storeId) {

            $table = $attribute->getBackend()->getTable();
            $select = $this->_getReadAdapter()->select()
                    ->from($table)
                    ->where('entity_type_id = ?', $attribute->getEntityTypeId())
                    ->where('attribute_id = ?', $attribute->getAttributeId())
                    ->where('store_id = ?', $this->getDefaultStoreId())
                    ->where('entity_id = ?', $object->getEntityId());
            $row = $this->_getReadAdapter()->fetchOne($select);

            if (!$row) {
                $bind = array(
                    'entity_type_id' => $attribute->getEntityTypeId(),
                    'attribute_id' => $attribute->getAttributeId(),
                    'store_id' => $this->getDefaultStoreId(),
                    'entity_id' => $object->getEntityId(),
                    'value' => $this->_prepareValueForSave($value, $attribute)
                );
                $this->_getWriteAdapter()->insertOnDuplicate($attribute->getBackend()->getTable(), $bind, array('value'));
            }
        }
```